# How to graphically edit pages like AllItems.aspx (extracted using SPSource) in a WSPBuilder solution?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wspbuilder, spsource

I've followed the 'SPSource_Starter_Guide_WSPBuilder.docx' tutorial and everything was correct.

But I've a question : once you've extracted the aspx pages + schema.xml, which tool can be used to edit a AllItems.aspx page in designer mode ?

This is not possible using SharePoint Designer or VisualStudio because the masterpage cannot be found once the pages are extracted from the site.

Any solution for this ?

I've also posted this question to http://spsource.codeplex.com/Thread/EditThreadDetail.aspx?ThreadId=85934 (Sorry for crossposting...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from jthake on [my question](http://spsource.codeplex.com/Thread/EditThreadDetail.aspx?ThreadId=85934) on the SPSource codeplex site:

> Unfortunately there is no visual
>   designer for these pages in SP2007 due
>   to the comments you made. You could
>   start hacking at the files to fix the
>   references, but obviously that would
>   then need to be corrected to then
>   deploy them in the WSP file.

So I will close this question.